# parse string containing number with minus on the right

Tags: java, string, parsing

I have a problem - is there any possibility to recognize in the text the negative number, that has a minus sign on the right?
E.g. I'm thinking about number like that: **1500.0-** (instead of -1500.0).
Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: yes, there are many possibilities to do this, what have you already tried?

Comment: Yes. It is possible. Do you have more questions?

Comment: I concur.  It's definitely possible.  There are many existence proofs, going back to the 1960s, at least.

Comment: DecimalFormat and applyPattern would allow you to specify it in one go, without any "programming" on your part.

Comment: Something like:

    `DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("###0.##-");
    Number result = format.parse(yourString);`

(Of course, then you have to figure out how to pry the value out of the Number object.)

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it possible, it is actually easier  to handle a trailing sign. You just convert the number as usual, continuing while you keep getting digits, then if it ends with a minus sign just negate it. Easier than having to remember a leading sign.

Despite the names of the methods provided in the JDK, this is not 'parsing', it is radix conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `charAt` or a `regular Expression`, and many more...

```
String s = "1500.00-";
if (s.charAt(s.length()-2) == '-'){
  //minus on the right.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First move the minus (if any) from the end to the start:

```
num = num.replaceAll("(.*)(-)?$", "$2$1");
```

The good thing here is that if there's no minus sign at the end, or yjr minus us alteady at the start, nothing change it made.

Then parse it as normal, eg:

```
double d = Double.parseDouble(num);
```

Comment: As a minor optimization, wouldn't it be faster to check `if(num.charAt(num.length()-1)=='-')` than to run a regex?

Comment: Lots more code and a premature optimisation: It might shave a @spacepope microsecond off the execution time. If this was being executed millions of time in a tight loop you might consider faster approaches, but for everyday code, the brevity and convenience outweighs the (small) performance hit.